# Using Java8 streams to filter list and get the first element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
 collectorConfiguration = Optional.ofNullable(recapPlacement.getPnetCode())
                    .map(pnetCode -> Optional.ofNullable(collectorConfigurations.stream()
                    .filter(c -> pnetCode.equals(c.getPnetCode()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())
                    .orElse(unknownExternalCollector))
                    .orElse(unknownExternalCollector);
```

Here in the above code

1) I want to return `unknownExternalCollector` if pnetCode is null 
    OR

2) I want to iterate `collectorConfigurations` and find atleast one
    record by using pnetCode, if there are no elements in the list that
    matches pnetCode then I want return `unknownExternalCollector`.
I am getting compilation error saying

```
orElse
(java.util.Optional<com.capitalone.omega.collectorservice.domain.CollectorConfiguration>)
in Optional cannot be applied om.capitalone.omega.collectorservice.domain.CollectorConfiguration
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify it as follows (there is no need to collect and then stream and call `findFirst`. You can use `flatMap` here)

```
collectorConfiguration = Optional.ofNullable(recapPlacement.getPnetCode())
            .flatMap(pnetCode -> collectorConfigurations.stream()
                    .filter(c -> pnetCode.equals(c.getPnetCode()))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .findFirst())
            .orElse(unknownExternalCollector);
```